# Product of a Rademacher and a standard normal random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Z \sim Rademacher$, and they are independent.

How can I show formally that $Y=XZ \sim N(0,1) $ too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just determine

$$P(XZ \le x) = P(-X \le x | Z =-1)P(Z=-1)+P(X \le x | Z =1)P(Z=1) $$

Now use the fact $X$ is independent of $Z$, then you have

$$P(XZ \le x) = \frac{P(X \ge -x)}{2}+\frac{P(X \le x)}{2} $$

Here just use $X \sim N(0,1)$, this gives you a symmetry, i.e., $P(X \ge -x)= P(X \le x)$. A simple drawing of the normal curve and you will see this. Or you can use the pdf function and change where you are integrating.

Hope this can help you!